# SQLAlchemy Installation in PyPy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, pypy

I have a database project that could greatly benefit from the speed boost PyPy provides. I have been unable to install one of the core libraries I am using, sqlalchemy, under PyPy, however. I drop it into the Site-Packges directory but then PyPy squawks at me, saying it also needs PyODBC, whose default source code does not include python files, but only .CPP files and headers. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What database backend are you trying to use with sqlalchemy?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server using the PyODBC driver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know standard pyodbc package currently can not run with PyPy without patches.

However, you can try [pypyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc), which is similar to pyodbc, and it enables running SQLAlchemy under PyPy. [This how-to](http://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/wiki/Enable_SQLAlchemy_on_PyPy) describes the 4 steps to enable it.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of pypyodbc.

Comment: I'll take a look. You misspelled "maintainer" ;)